# How to send SES email to multiple recipients using STMP approach in Python (AWS Lambda)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I am going about the lambda function and ses for email messages slightly different than AWS documentation and was wondering if anyone can help guide how I can add multiple email addresses to my '*to*' clause.

Here is my current script that pulls data from s3 and sends to respective address - goal is to add more addresses.

```
import json
import psycopg2
import boto3
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from io import StringIO 
import io
import sys
import logging
import os
import csv
import smtplib
from base64 import b64decode
import email
#import build_table
from pretty_html_table import build_table
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib


s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3_bucket = 'data-##########'
ACCESS_KEY = '#################'
SECRET_KEY = '###############################'
ses = boto3.client('ses', 
    aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY, 
    aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY, 
    region_name = 'us-west-1',
    endpoint_url = 'https://email-smtp.#############')


def get_data():
    bucket = 'data-###########'
    key = 'subset_df.csv'
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    # This should prevent the 2GB download limit from a python ssl internal
    chunks = (chunk for chunk in obj["Body"].iter_chunks(chunk_size=1024**3))
    data = io.BytesIO(b"".join(chunks)) # This keeps everything fully in memory
    df = pd.read_csv(data) # here you can provide also some necessary args and kwargs
    #print(df)
    df_table = pd.DataFrame(df)
    return df_table

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data = get_data()
    # get SES smtp email credentials from Secrets Manager
    
    body = build_table(data, 'blue_light')
    print(data)
    #body = build_table(x, 'blue_light')
    sender = "default_01@gmail.com"
    to = "janedoe@gmail.com"
    cc = "johndoe@gmail.com"
    smtphost = 'email-smtp.###############'
    # send email
    #body = build_table(x, 'blue_light')
    rcpt = cc.split(",") + to.split(",")
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = "test"
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = to
    body1 = """<H3>Hello,
            <br>
            Below is today's report on bucket listings"""
    body3 = """
        <br>
        Please reach out to BI national ops dashboard for more information: https://test.com
        <br>
        regards,
        <br>
        BI Ops Team
        """
    
    body_content = body1+body+body3
    #print(body_content)
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body_content, "html"))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body_content, 'plain'))
    tt = msg.attach(MIMEText(body_content, 'plain'))
    print(tt)
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtphost)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY)
    server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['to'], msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
    return("email sent successfully.")
```

I tried adding a cc porition and then comma seperate the to and cc as *rcpt* variable and then add that into the server.sendmail line of code but got an error that says

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "'NoneType' object is not iterable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 89, in lambda_handler\n    server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['rcpt'], msg.as_string())\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py\", line 889, in sendmail\n    for each in to_addrs:\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you send a normal mail with just a single recipient?

Comment: Note that you set for the key To and From but later read from to and from.

Comment: Yes I can send the output fine to 1 recipient (although its sent to junk)

Comment: Sorry not following your 'To' and 'From' comment